# Hausdorff measure, volume form, reference

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, volume, geometric-measure-theory

Could you tell me where I can find a reference to the fourth corollary in this [encyclopedia](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Area_formula)?

> Corollary $4$:
>
> Assume that $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is an $n$-dimensional $C^1$
>   submanifold. Then the Hausdorff dimension of $\Sigma$ is $n$ and, for
>   any relatively open set $U \subset \Sigma$ $$\mathcal{H}^n(U)= 
> \int_U \mathrm{dvol}$$ where $\mathrm{dvol}$ denotes the usual volume form of
>   $\Sigma$ as Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$

It is also stated in [this article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Volume_form#Area_formula) of the encyclopedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that what you ask is a particular instance of Theorem 2.10.10 (page 176) of

H. Federer "Geometric Measure Theory" (Springer 1969) 
([here the Zmath reference](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an:00844032))

Comment: So in my case this theorem says that if we have $f: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^m$, then $\mathcal{H}^n(U) = \int N(f|_U, y) d \mu (y)$, where $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$. Did I get it wrong? What should we take $\mu$ to be in order to get the volume form?

Comment: $\mu$ is not the $m$-dimensional volume form, but the $n$-dimensional one (that is to say, the volume form of the restriction of the metric of $\mathbb R^m$ to $\Sigma$) concentrated on $f(\Sigma)$. I don't have federer book ant hand now, but if I remember, in the federer's terminology it is probably  $\mu=\mathcal T^n$. The chapter of the book about the Caratheodory's construction (It should be chapter 2.10) contains all details. It is not easy to read, I know, but that's Federer!

Comment: You remeber correctly. I've found $\mathcal{T}^m$ in Federer. It is the result of Carath. constr. for $X=  \mathbb{R}^n, \ m $ a positive integer  $$\zeta (S) = \alpha (m) 2^{-m} \sup \{ |a_1 - b_1| \wedge ... \wedge |a_m - b_m| \ : \ a_1, b_1, ... a_m, b_m \in  S \}$$ fdr $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ - this is a "quote" from Federer's GMT. So we need to consider $\mathcal{T}^n$ for $S \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ to get the statement in my question?

Comment: @Bilbo yes, I think so

Comment: That's good. Thank you!